# Relation does not exist on postgresql database with Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I made a model in my Django DB. I did migrations and now I am getting this error. I removed everything I did, deleted the migration files, and it is fine. But now when I add the model back, I get the same error.

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/omegavalidator/bugscenario/
relation "omegavalidator_bugscenario" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "omegavalidator_bugscenari...

The above exception (relation "omegavalidator_bugscenario" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "omegavalidator_bugscenari... ^ ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

I am looking at the table to my database and I see no references to omegavalidator_bugscenario. I removed the only reference in it in my code as well. Right now it is just a model that is not being used. I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Looks like you've messed up your migrations. If it a non production DB I'd just delete the DB and delete all the migration files and rerun makemigrations, migrate again.

Comment: It'll be much quicker than trying to fix this.

Comment: It is production.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an easy fix. I am new at this so I am not sure if this is the correct/easiest way to fix it but what I did was drop the table and then let Django recreate it.